# Can't disable SAFE or change SAFE mode

Tags: transmitter, receiver, spektrum

I was gifted [one of these](https://hobbyking.com/en_us/t-28-funfighter-epo-650mm-pnf.html?___store=en_us) (with souped-up motor and ESC) and was delighted when I discovered it could be bound to my Spektrum DXS transmitter. However, the receiver is stuck in beginner mode. I've been unable disable SAFE or change it to expert mode.

The plane holds the control surfaces at an angle when I hold the plane sideways, limits the throw and prevents me from applying any down elevator, indicating to me that it's in beginner mode (although this is my first plane with SAFE so I'm not certain). The SAFE only activates after I first increase the throttle - prior to that it behaves fully manually. This is extremely annoying as I consider myself a competent pilot and wish to be in full control of the aircraft.

I tried moving all of the switches on my transmitter but none changed the mode. I thought possibly the previous owner had a transmitter with more channels and bound the SAFE control to a channel which no longer exists, so I tried [these instructions](https://www.rcgroups.com/forums/showthread.php?3094362-Safe-Select-assignment-to-a-switch) to bind it to channel 5 on my transmitter but it didn't work.

It's possible that this is linked to an issue where the motor only works if I re-calibrate the ESC every time I turn it on.

My receiver has the part number eflr310013 and is described in [this manual](https://www.spektrumrc.com/ProdInfo/Files/EFL3100-Manual_EN.pdf) for an E-Flite Apprentice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a solution the next day.

I noticed that while holding down the panic button (A button on the transmitter, channel 6), I appeared to have full control of the controls. This led me to realise that the channel was operating in the wrong direction and so the plane was always in panic mode - this also explains the problem with the ESC. I reversed the direction of the button on my transmitter and it now functions correctly.